# How can I import a JS variable in React HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JS file that renders the raw markup that the server file uses for client to receive through webpack, especially stuff that needs to be loaded in `<head>`, to avoid having any static `.html` files in the project. I've' defined some config variables in this file that are needed at runtime from 3rd party scripts:

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
... // other imports

`<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charSet="utf-8">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/main.css">
      <script>
        var config1 = {
          key1: 'value1',
          key2: 'value2',
          key3: 'value3',
        };
        var config2 = [
          {
            someKey1: 'value1',
            someKey2: 'value2',
            someKey3: 'value3',
          },
          {
            someKey1: 'value4',
            someKey2: 'value5',
            someKey3: 'value6',
          },
          {
            someKey1: 'value7',
            someKey2: 'value8',
            someKey3: 'value9',
          },
        ]
        // other JS scripts like GTM for google tag manager, analytics etc
      </script>
      ....`;
```

I would like to pull the configs from a config file instead of var declaration inside the `js` file, something like this:

configuration.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

module.exports = {
  var config1 = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
  };
  var config2 = [
    {
      someKey1: 'value1',
      someKey2: 'value2',
      someKey3: 'value3',
    },
    {
      someKey1: 'value4',
      someKey2: 'value5',
      someKey3: 'value6',
    },
    {
      someKey1: 'value7',
      someKey2: 'value8',
      someKey3: 'value9',
    },
  ]
};
```

and then use them as..

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { config1, config2 } from '../src/configuration';
... // other imports


`<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charSet="utf-8">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/main.css">
      <script>
        ${config1}
        ${config2}
        // other JS scripts like GTM for google tag manager, analytics etc
      </script>
....`;
```

But all I get is this when I look at the page source, am instead expecting the variable values

```
[object Object]
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

How can I import the config variables so I dont have to overcrowd my render file since these configs are static and will never change.

Answer (score 0):

The string interpolation `${}` automatically calls the `.toString()` property of every object and hence you see `[object Object]`.This can be seen by calling `Object.prototype.toString.call( {} );`.

One thing I can suggest is to use an iteration to dynamically update the value. Something like `${ Object.keys( config1 ).forEach( key => config1[ key ] )}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the config files as .json and use a json loader to import the data into your components with a regular import es6 statement.

Comment: the issue is I need the imported value to include the entire variable not just its value, because the 3rd party script is iterating over `config1` and `config2` variables, so I literally need the definition of these 2 vars available as global variables

Comment: @user988544 you can use import config1 from './config1' and use config1 as the variable name.